# How to prove that the germs $Z(\mathfrak{m})$ and $Z(\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}})$ are the same.

Tags: analytic-geometry, analytic-functions

Here $m\in\mathbb{K}^n$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_m$. I don't know how to prove this stament. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Your question as stated looks very easy, since $Z(\mathfrak{m})$ is assumedly the same thing as $Z(\mathfrak{m})$.

Comment: Of course. It was missing the square root symbol. Thank you